# Minestra, minestrone, e zuppa

Tags: word-meaning, word-usage, word-choice, difference, cooking

Che differenza c'è tra il significato delle parole minestra, minestrone, e zuppa? Grazie.

Comment: @apaderno Please, stop removing the tag as soon as it's added back. Several members of the community think it's good and it's ***your*** opinion against theirs. If you want to discuss the topic, do it in Meta. I removed the comments, because they belong elsewhere.

Comment: @egreg I do not think there are several members who think they are good. Instead of blatantly revert the last edit, which is removing unrelated tags, it should be probably better to just add the relevant tags. This question is about the difference between two words; it does not ask about meaning, usage, or choice.

Comment: It rather seems that somebody thinks that who adds tags is always correct, and who remove tags are always wrong.

Comment: @apaderno I believe that the tag is correct. So we're at least three against one.

Comment: @egreg That is still not "several."

Comment: Also, if [tag:cooking] is really "correct," that does not mean that [tag:word-meaning], [tag:word-usage], and [tag:word-choice] are correct too. Since those are added back too, this is not anymore a matter of "correct tags," but of "I do not like your edit." (In fact, Elements in Space has never complained about the other tags removal.)

Answer (score 5):

La definizione di `minestra` è decisamente regionale.

A Napoli, per esempio, si chiama **minestra maritata** un piatto di verdure bollite in un brodo a base di carne. Sempre in ambito regionale, più in generale, di solito si intende per minestra un piatto in cui la pasta è cotta insieme agli altri ingredienti in poca acqua, fino a ridurre il tutto a una consistenza piuttosto cremosa (come per esempio nella [pasta e piselli](http://lacuocagalante.com/recipe-items/pasta-e-piselli/)), in un procedimento che ricorda quello dei risotti, anche se con differenze significative.

[Secondo Wikipedia](https://it.wikipedia.org/wiki/Minestra) la definizione italiana di `minestra` è in realtà molto generica, e include tutti i primi piatti, comprese le zuppe e i minestroni, passando per le pastasciutte e perfino i timballi al forno.

Sul `minestrone` ci sono pochi dubbi: è un piatto di verdure miste cotte e servite in brodo.

La `zuppa` è solitamente un piatto caldo a base di legumi accompagnato da pane raffermo o abbrustolito. Il fatto che siano zuppe sia la zuppa di fagioli che quella di pesce sottolinea che il punto in comune delle zuppe sia di fatto il pane. Un altro esempio particolare è la **zuppa di latte**, in cui il pane viene immerso nel latte caldo.

In sintesi, la differenza fra minestra, minestrone e zuppa dipende molto dalla cultura regionale, ma a grandi linee e con diverse significative eccezioni:

- la **minestra** è di solito un piatto in cui la pasta viene fatta cuocere, in maniera in qualche modo simile al risotto, insieme agli altri ingredienti, come nella pasta e piselli o nella pasta e patate.
- il **minestrone** è un piatto connotato da una grande varietà di verdure cotte e servite in brodo.
- la **zuppa** è un piatto dalle origini povere in cui il pane è accompagnato da altri ingredienti in preparazioni brodose o cremose: soprattutto legumi, ma anche pesce misto o carne.

Comment: Benvenuto su Italian.SE!

Comment: @Charo Grazie! Spero non sia un problema il fatto che debba usare una tastiera americana, quindi senza lettere accentate. Magari ci sono modi per ovviare che non conosco?

Comment: Forse dal tuo sistema operativo potresti impostare una tastiera che ti permetta di scrivere gli accenti.

Comment: @lupalberto Consiglio fortemente la tastiera americana con tasti muti (codice us_intl), la trovo decisamente migliore della tastiera italiana per scrivere l'italiano :)

Comment: @DenisNardin: Anch'io uso questa tastiera per scrivere in italiano, in catalano, in spagnolo...

Comment: C'è del marcio in Danimarca.... funziona! Grazie @DenisNardin e @Charo!

Comment: Vorrei aggiungere che in Romagna "Minestra" vuol dire "Primo piatto"

Answer (score 3):

Si tratta di tre pietanze diverse. Le descrivo qui di seguito, con il caveat che l'uso probabilmente varia nelle diverse regioni d'Italia (e, probabilmente, di casa in casa).

- **Minestra** Si tratta di pasta molto piccola e sottile ([esempio](http://www.barilla.it/prodotto-barilla/filini-alluovo-0)) cotta nel brodo. La procedura è essenzialmente la stessa che per cucinare la pasta, con la differenza che non si aggiunge il sale, che il tempo di cottura è molto più corto e che alla fine non si scola.
- **Zuppa** Si tratta grosso modo della stessa cosa che in inglese si chiama *soup*: un misto di verdure e carne lessate e mangiate spesso mettendo pezzi di pane.
- **Minestrone** Grosso modo una zuppa con la pasta, io di solito la cucino con pasta lunga (spesso tagliatelle) ma è comune anche con pasta corta.

Answer (score 0):

Il significato dei tre termini zuppa minestra e minestrone non è molto distinto e varia secondo i luoghi, come già detto. Per aggiungere qualche cosa, per come mi risulta, io direi che, a grandi linee:

**Zuppa** è un piatto con presenza di liquido, dove c'è un ingrediente dominante: Zuppa di pesce, Zuppa di ceci, Zuppa di latte (quest'ultima io la chiamo semplicemente zuppa o caffellatte); può essere più o meno densa (ma non asciutta);

**Minestra** dovrebbe essere un piatto brodoso o (un po') cremoso con diversi ingredienti, generalmente vegetali, in cui non se ne trova uno dominante. Si può dire "Minestra di ceci"; ma di solito non si dice "Minestra di latte" o "Minestra di pesce";

**Minestrone** è una minestra densa, ricca, con tanti ingredienti vegetali, fatta cuocere a lungo. Noto che l'uso traslato di "Minestrone" può indicare un'accozzaglia disordinata di parecchi elementi, come: "Il discorso che ha fatto è un minestrone di concetti astrusi".

A parte la "zuppa" (di latte, o caffellatte), tutte le preparazioni possono contenere pasta e tutte tranne la zuppa di pesce possono contenere brodo di carne o pezzetti di carne.

Aggiungo **Minestrina** che, al contrario del minestrone, è molto liquida e ha pochi ingredienti; e **Brodo** che è una versione di minestrina ancora più essenziale ridotta appunto al solo liquido (brodo).